# how can we know the address of the peers in Private ethereum block chain to send the transactions

Tags: go-ethereum

Hi iam new to private ethereum block chain and geth. Can anybody suggest me how can we know the receivers address to send the transaction using geth console on sender side?

Answer (score 0):

If you know how to use geth javascript console then you can use the this web3js command to get all of the accounts from your private network: `web3.eth.getAccounts()`

Comment: But it retuens the EOA of same node but not the other node? How can i know the Receivers address to send the transactions?

Comment: What i understand from your question is that you have a private blockchain running on geth but dont know all the address account on that private chain to send transaction, is that right? if not then can you give me a more specific example

Comment: Firstly,Thank you for the reply. I hope this example would give you clear picture of my question .consider there are two nodes(n1,n2) running on my private block chain. and each node have their own EOA addresses.when we try using web3.eth.getAccounts() command on n1 geth console it would only give the account address that are present only on n1 but not on n2. So, if i want send a transaction from n1 to n2, how can I access the  address of n2 from n1 geth console to send the transaction ?

Comment: havent try this yet but maybe using web3 personnal getAccount will work you can read more at here: https://web3js.readthedocs.io/en/1.0/web3-eth-personal.html#getaccounts. You need to setup the personnal node at the start of site above